# How do I read and append to a text file in one pass?

Tags: python, file, file-writing, file-read

I want to check if a string is inside a text file and then append that string if it's not there.

I know I can probably do that by creating two separate `with` methods, one for reading and another for appending, but is it possible to read and append inside the same `with` method?

The closest I came up with is this:

```
with open("file.txt","r+") as file:
    content=file.read()
    print("aaa" in content)
    file.seek(len(content))
    file.write("\nccccc")
```

My file.txt:

```
aaaaa
bbbbb
```

When I run the code for the first time, I get this:

```
aaaaa
bbbbb
ccccc
```

but if I run it again, this comes up:

```
aaaaa
bbbbb
ccc
ccccc
```

I would expect the third line to be `ccccc`.

Anyone can explain why the last two characters are truncated in the second run? Also, how do I read and append text to a file?

Comment: Using `read()` will place the pointer at the end of the file already; there should be no need to `seek()`.

Comment: I ran this code and the characters are not truncated(python 2 and 3).

Comment: @A.S `file.seek(len(content))` is not the right way to do it use `file.seek(-1, os.SEEK_END)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use `seek` on text-files. The length of the contents is not the length of the file in all cases. Either use binary file reading or use two separate withs:

```
with open("file.txt","r") as file:
    content=file.read()
print("aaa" in content)
with open("file.txt","a") as file:
    file.write("\nccccc")
```

Comment: How seek(0) or seek(-1) can spoil everything?

Comment: I would say seek(0) or seek(0,2). In official docs, seek(0,2) is treated as a normay way of seeking the end of the file.

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
with open("file.txt","r+") as file:
    content=file.read()
    file.seek(0,2)
    file.write("\nccccc")
```

Here we use `fileObject.seek(offset[, whence])` with `offset 0` & `whence 2` that is seek to 0 characters from the end. And then write to the file.

OR (Alternate using SEEK_END):

```
import os
with open("file.txt", 'rb+') as file:
    file.seek(-1, os.SEEK_END)
    file.write("\nccccc\n")
```

Here we seek to `SEEK_END` of the file(with the os package) and then write to it.

Answer (score 2):

Why not do this? Note, the first `with` statement is used for creating the file, not for reading or appending. So this solutions uses only one with to read and append.

```
string="aaaaa\nbbbbb"
with open("myfile", "w") as f:
    f.write(string)

with open("myfile", "r+") as f:
    if not "ccccc" in f.read():
        f.write("\nccccc")
```

Answer (score 1):

`seek()` is based on bytes, and your text file may not be encoded with precisely one byte per character. Since `read()` reads the whole file and leaves the pointer at the end, there's no need to seek anyway. Just remove that line from your code and it will work fine.

```
with open("file.txt","r+") as file:
    content=file.read()
    print("aaa" in content)
    file.write("\nccccc")
```

Comment: Someone on the southern hemisphere must have swapped the vote buttons. Why is it -1, this is the best answer.

Comment: That someone on the southern hemisphere probably ran the code.
@try-catch-finally Have you tried it?
You get : `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 0] Error`

Comment: @AniMenon - I don't know whether try-catch-finally tried it, but I did before I posted, and it worked perfectly for me.

Comment: @AniMenon - And I got perfect output. I cannot reproduce your error.

Comment: @AniMenon - What versions of Python and Windows are you using?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Windows 10 & python3

Comment: And I'm on 8.1 and 3. Works perfectly here. I don't know what the problem is with your setup, but I think it is indeed a problem with your setup and not with the code.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 probably yes. Because I tried it on my Linux machine and it worked.